# Flutter Animation no duration

Tags: flutter, animation, dart

I have a stateful widget which I am attempted to transition the textStyle like below.

```
AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                child: Text(word),
                style: hideWord
                    ? TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)
                    : TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              ),
```

However the animation is instant and doesn't take the defined 3 seconds to complete, in fact there is no animation at all just a change from black to white text rather than the duration set in the animationDefaultTextStyle.

I am triggering the animation via the following from another stateful widget on click event.

```
cardlist[currentCardIndex].hideWord = true;
```

What am I missing here? I could implement BLOC and add a listener to the card widget and then setState, but that seems like overkill for what should be a basic trigger.

Comment: *"However the animation happens as soon as the widget loads,"* - `duration: Duration(seconds: 3)` means the duration of the animation, not when it starts

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was incorrect. The transition from black to white is instant.  It doesn't take 3 seconds.

Comment: `class FooText extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FooTextState createState() => _FooTextState();
}

class _FooTextState extends State<FooText> {
var colors = [Colors.black, Colors.orange];
var idx = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
child: InkWell(
onTap: () => setState(() => idx ^= 1),
child: Center(child: Text('click me')),
),
style: TextStyle(
color: colors[idx],
fontSize: 64,
),
duration: 500.milliseconds,
);
}
}`

Comment: and? does it animate colors in 500ms timespan?

Comment: I will test this avo. Thanks for the code

Comment: How is this any different from what I am doing? You are triggering the animation within the same class, where I am not. Otherwise it looks the same.

Comment: i dont know - i saw only `AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(...)` part of your code

Comment: so, does the code i posted work for you? and if your code still does not work post the minimal part to test

Comment: No, it doesn't work unfortunately. I will update the posted code with the full app.

Comment: the code i posted does not work? how come?

Comment: I works perfectly if I call trigger the animation in the same class. However the problem is triggering the animation from a different stateful Widget. Parent widget trigger child widget animation

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start your animation 3 second after widget load .. you can use below code...

Animation Duration is one Second

```
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  var hideWord = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        hideWord = false;
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          child: Text("word"),
          style: hideWord
              ? TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)
              : TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My explanation was incorrect,  the animation or transition occurs in an instant rather than  over the duration of 3 seconds

Comment: your welcome ! did you try above code ?  I tried  to make what you want ...